# Display image after a condition in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

I am trying to display an image once the user clicks on Chicken category, I was able to change the colour only.

```
   {categories && categories.map(category => (
        <motion.div 
        whileTap={{scale:0.75}}
        key={categories.id} className={`group ${
          filter === category.urlParamName}group ${ filter === "chicken"? 
          'bg-red-500': 'bg-card'} } 
          w-24 min-w-[94px] h-28 cursor-pointer rounded-lg drop-shadow-xl flex flex-col 
        gap-3 items-center justify-center hover:bg-cartNumBg`}
        onClick={()=> setFilter(category.urlParamName)      
        } >
```

Comment: I think some typo is happening in the `className`, please check thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the className's closing bracket before the w-24.

```
<motion.div
      whileTap={{ scale: 0.75 }}
      key={categories.id}
      className={`group ${filter === category.urlParamName}group ${
        filter === "chicken" ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-card"
      } w-24 min-w-[94px] h-28 cursor-pointer rounded-lg drop-shadow-xl flex 
      flex-col gap-3 items-center justify-center hover:bg-cartNumBg`}
      onClick={() => setFilter(category.urlParamName)}
    />
```